# How can I hide default <select> <option> when the drop-down is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

I want to have a `<select>` element that's default chosen option is "____".  In other word's, blank.

When the drop-down is focused, I want the "____" option to not be in the options that can be selected.  That way the user has to choose something other than "____" as their option.

Does that make sense?

## Illustrations

### Closed:

[image: Closed select menu]

### Opened:

[image: Opened select menu]

As you can see, the option "___" is not in the list when it is being selected.  That is my desired end result.

I've tried using `onFocus` events to remove options, but that just unfocuses the element, and replaces the default option with another one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To hide the default option, allowing the others to show, there are a few ways to go.

**Unfortunately, you can't hide option elements in all browsers.** Again, `display:none;` does not work in all browsers on `options` ...

In the past when I have needed to do this, I have set their disabled attribute, like so...

```
$('option').prop('disabled', true);
```

I've then used the hiding where it is supported in browsers using this piece of CSS...

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

You can leverage the `hidden` attribute in HTML. Try with this example

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/pm7cefvg/1/) or the screenshots below.

Before clicking:
[image: before clicking]

After clicking:
[image]

Comment: Can you append similar functionality for multiple select as well. This doesn't seem to work for multiple and the dropdown is open by default.

Answer (score 6):

**CSS** is your friend, set `display:none` for the option you want to hide.

```
<select>
<option style="display:none" selected="selected" value=""> </option>
<option value="visi1">Visible1</option>
<option value="visi2">Visible2</option>
<option value="visi3">Visible3</option>
</select>
```

Here's an extra with jQuery that will ensure the first option of any select is invisible:

```
$('select:first-child').css({display:none;});
```