# How to hide the first option in select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the "Day" option. It should only appear if nothing is selected.

```
<select id="day" name="day">
    <option disabled selected>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

How it looks at the moment: https://imgur.com/a/tK3bHDX

I tried adding "hidden" to the first option but it didn't work either. I use Safari as my web browser. Maybe that's the reason I don't know.

```
<option disabled selected hidden>Day</option>
```

Comment: why do you need to hide it? if you select another option, the day option is disabled, is working as expected

Comment: Yes, it is disabled, but I want it to disappear @ChrisG

Comment: are you in any framework??

Comment: is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350843/how-can-i-hide-default-select-option-when-the-drop-down-is-clicked

Comment: Tried all of them @Kamran it's not working for me :(

Comment: can you not just use `display:none`?  then it will appear like placeholder text but when you click on the select, it won't be in the list of options: https://jsfiddle.net/es0rvz3y/2

Comment: Not working :D @Pete

Comment: You'll probably need to use some sort of js plugin like select2 then, so you can apply styles that will work in safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need by any chance?
use querySelector to get the element of your disabled option and compare, if another option was selected then hide it

```js
function handleDayChange(selectElement) {
    const selectedValue = selectElement.value;
    let dayOption = selectElement.querySelector('option:disabled');

    if (selectedValue !== "") {
        dayOption.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dayOption.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="day" name="day" onchange="handleDayChange(this)">
    <option disabled selected>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Code doesn't work. When I run your code snippet it doesn't work either. Maybe it's because I'm using Safari?

Comment: I'm using chrome and it works here so yeah

Answer (score -2):

In HTML, you cannot directly hide the first option in a  element using only HTML and CSS. However, you can use a combination of JavaScript and CSS to achieve this. Here's an example using JavaScript to hide the first option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hide First Option</title>
  <style>
    /* Hide the first option */
    #mySelect option:first-child {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option...</option>
   <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
 </select>

  <script>
  / JavaScript to handle hiding the first option
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var selectElement = document.getElementById("mySelect");
// Hide the first option
selectElement.options[0].style.display = "none";
  });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

In this example:

The CSS style display: none; is used to hide the first option.
The JavaScript code is wrapped in an event listener for the DOMContentLoaded event to ensure that the script runs after the document has been fully loaded.
The JavaScript code selects the  element with the id "mySelect" and hides the first option by setting its display style property to "none".
Keep in mind that using JavaScript may not be suitable in all situations, especially if you're working in an environment where JavaScript is disabled. If JavaScript is not an option, consider restructuring your HTML to place the default option at the end or use a placeholder option that doesn't need to be hidden.

Comment: Did you try your code? Or is it rather ChatGPT generated code ..?

Comment: Code is not working :(